# Adjust size of shading in node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shading

I defined a shade according to:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spindiff}{0.5 cm}
    {color(0 cm)=(gray); color(3 cm)=(black); color(7 cm)=(gray)}
\pgfuseshading{spindiff}
```

Now I want to use the same shading several times and change the height of the shading. I tried to wrap is in a `\newcommand`, but this does not work. See the MWE below. How can I define the shade once, and use it several times thereby varying the height.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\shading[1]{
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spindiff}
    {#1}{color(0 cm)=(gray); color(3 cm)=(black); color(7 cm)=(gray)}
    \pgfuseshading{spindiff}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shading{0.5 cm}
        \node (channelside) {\pgfuseshading{spindiff}}; 
        \shading{2 cm}
        \node[yshift=-3 cm] (channelside) {\pgfuseshading{spindiff}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

The top one should be 4 times smaller than the bottom one, which it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to getting shadings to scale automatically is just really a question of thinking carefully about the details in the Ti*k*Z manual. The thing to remember is that only the central part of the shading will typically be shown.

For correct scaling, we want to declare a `100bp x 100bp` shading and to assume that only the part from `(25bp,25bp)` to `(75bp,75bp)` will be shown. (Sometimes, more or less is shown, but we're not rotating or anything so we can ignore those complications.)

Then you can just say how large the node should be and let Ti*k*Z scale the shading appropriately.

For example:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spindif}{100bp}{color(0bp)=(gray); color(25bp)=(gray); color(46bp)=(black); color(75bp)=(gray); color(100bp)=(gray)}
```

Note that the part from `0bp` to `25bp` won't be shown so we make it plain `gray` and similarly for the part from `75bp` to `100bp`. `46bp` is approximately 3/7 of the distance between `25bp` and `75bp` i.e. 3/7 of the way across the visible part of the shading.

For convenience, we can define a style for our nodes which sets the width to `70mm`, adjusts the height according to an argument and fills the node with the shading.

```
\tikzset{%
  spin diff/.style={minimum height=#1, minimum width=70mm, shading=spindif},
}
```

Then we can write, for example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (channelside 1) [spin diff=5mm] {};
  \node (channelside 2) [spin diff=20mm, yshift=-30mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: scaled shadings]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spindif}{100bp}{color(0bp)=(gray); color(25bp)=(gray); color(46bp)=(black); color(75bp)=(gray); color(100bp)=(gray)}
\tikzset{%
  spin diff/.style={minimum height=#1, minimum width=70mm, shading=spindif},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (channelside 1) [spin diff=5mm] {};
  \node (channelside 2) [spin diff=20mm, yshift=-30mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I read it in the manual, but I did not understand it and could not get it to work. Is there any reason why the `bp` units are used for shades?

Comment: @Roald Maybe just that they are the most basic units but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was quite simple: the `\pgfuseshading{spindiff}` in the `\newcommand` was screwing things up.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\shading[1]{
        \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{spindiff}{#1}
            {color(0 cm)=(gray); color(3 cm)=(black); color(7 cm)=(gray)
        }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shading{0.5 cm}
        \node (channelside) {\pgfuseshading{spindiff}}; 
        \shading{2 cm}
        \node[yshift=-3 cm] (channelside) {\pgfuseshading{spindiff}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Why do it this way? Shadings get automatically scaled and this works fine if the shading is declared appropriately. Note that you are not using the same shading each time but creating a new one.

Comment: @cfr I could not get them to scale automatically. At least I tried some things to no avail. Any tips?

Comment: You have to read the fine print :-). See my answer below.