# tikz radial shading starting in corner and staying circular

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am trying to reproduce a shading similar to the following picture:
[image: desiredResult]
As you can see, the shading starts in the upper left corner and the rings of colors are circles. However, the shading also correctly scales with the size of the rectangle. It always fills the area reasonable and the rings stay circles. This result is produced with Powerpoint.

Now I want to reproduce the same (or at least similar) with LaTeX. After considering several questions and answers (e.g. [Can Tikz implement multi stop gradient fills with adjustable positions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286984/can-tikz-implement-multi-stop-gradient-fills-with-adjustable-positions)), I came up with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{fradial}{\pgfpoint{-40bp}{40bp}}{
  rgb(0)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
  rgb(13bp)=(1.0,0.0,0.0);
  rgb(32bp)=(0.0,1.0,0.0);
  rgb(40bp)=(0.0,0.0,1.0)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[shading=fradial] (0,0) rectangle (34,11);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following result:
[image]
It is kind of similar, but not close enough. There are currently two issues:

1. the shading does not correctly start in the upper left corner
2. the shading is distorted to be elliptical rather than cyclical.

I guess that the first point has something to do with the thing mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332551/adjust-size-of-shading-in-node), that part of the shading is not used. Unfortunately I do not fully understand the section in the tikz manual. I thought I had and scaled my values up to `100bp` but then I almost had just the black part in my frame. That was weird.

So how can I achieve both: correct start in the upper left corner and keeping the shading cyclical.

I am afraid the solution will be something with clipping. But I am very interested in the solutions, which come up.

One more thing. For simplicity of the MWE I reproduced my result with the `\fill`-command. Later the shading shall be applied to a `\node`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much J Leon V. and user272921 for pointing in the right direction. With this information I was able to construct a solution.

First thing: I now have understood how the scaling of the radial shading works. In the pgfmanual it is described in detail for horizontal shading, but not for radial ones. Radial shadings are scaled such that the color defined for 25bp lays exactly on the border of the path bounding box to be shaded. For my rectangle that meant, that the color for 25bp is exactly on the edges of the rectangle.

Furthermore, the specified point in the `\pgfdeclareradialshading` does not shift the shading but rather distort it. This creates weird results if the shifting point is actually outside the circle. I should have printed the shading with `\pgfuseshading` earlier to notice that.

Combining these two findings with especially the `path picture` (which also clips conveniently) created a good result:

[image: new result]

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{fradial}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{
    rgb(0)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    rgb(9bp)=(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    rgb(20bp)=(0.0,0.690,0.314);
    rgb(25bp)=(0.0,0.690,0.941)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        myshading/.style = {
            path picture={
                \fill[shading=fradial]
                    let 
                        \p0 = (path picture bounding box.north west),
                        \p1 = ($ (path picture bounding box.south east) - (path picture bounding box.north west) $),
                        \n0 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
                        \p{upper left} = (\x0-\n0, \y0+\n0),
                        \p{lower right} = (\x0 + \n0, \y0 - \n0)
                    in
                        (\p{upper left}) rectangle (\p{lower right});
            }
        }
    ]

    \Huge
    \node[minimum width = 34 cm, minimum height = 11 cm, text=white,myshading] at (0,0) {Hello World};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

First I moved the definition of the shading outside of the document to eliminate some additional whitespace, which was created by that.

I used the color definition as I used it in Powerpoint (sorry, I should have done that in the original question in the first place, but did not expect someone to look after the colors, as I was more interested in the principle).

Inside the `path picture` I do some calculations to automatically calculate the size of the square, which needs to be drawn to get the correct shading. It needs to be a square so that the colors are actually circles and not ellipses. And it needs to be a bit bigger so that the color of 25bp is not on the edge of the rectangle but rather in the far corner. Otherwise the lower right corner would be black (one can test that by replacing the definition of `\n0` by `\n0={max(abs(\x1),abs(\y1))}`.

In this solution almost no magic numbers are involved, despite the weird 25bp. Everything else is computed automatically.

When comparing to the desired result it is not a 100% match, because the shading itself seems to be calculated differently. So adding more points as J. Leon V. has done would help. But in the end it is now far close than I would have ever imagined.

Comment: +1, it's the most elegant solution...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\clip` on a shaded square. It is easier if you change the definition of your shading.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{fradial}{\pgfpoint{0bp}{0bp}}{
  rgb(0)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
  rgb(13bp)=(1.0,0.0,0.0);
  rgb(32bp)=(0.0,1.0,0.0);
  rgb(40bp)=(0.0,0.0,1.0)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) rectangle (34,-11);
        \fill[shading=fradial] (-34,-34) rectangle (34,34);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks fairly easy from the code side. Unfortunately the shading lacks the blue part as it is apparently scaled too big. How would this solution be applied to a node, whose size is not known in advance?

Comment: You can do that with `path picture`, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some tricks to achieve it like modifiying the shaded square, some colorpicker to obtain the desired colos , and of course using `\clip.`

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfdeclareradialshading{fradial}{\pgfpoint{-34bp}{34bp}}{
        rgb(0bp)=(0,0,0);
        rgb(9bp)=(0.2,0,0);
        rgb(14bp)=(1,0,0);
        rgb(20bp)=(0.42,0.39,0.17);
        rgb(24bp)=(0.015,0.675,0.304);%4, 173, 78
        rgb(26bp)=(0.015,0.675,0.304);%4, 173, 78
        rgb(28bp)=(0,0.687,0.546);%0, 176, 140
        rgb(32bp)=(0,0.687,0.917);%0, 176, 235
        rgb(36bp)=(0,0.687,0.917)%0, 176, 140
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) rectangle ++(34,11);
        \fill[shading=fradial] (0,-21) rectangle ++(34,38); %(34,11);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the color picker effort. I did not really care about the exact color match, but obviously should have to avoid ambiguity. Did you add so many points to the gradient to get a better match? In Powerpoint actually just four colors are defined for the gradient. You changed also the values for the various positions. So now it is even more magic number like than my example. Is there any reasoning behind the values, or did you fiddle around until it worked? I am asking, because the size of the box will change (maybe even automatically when it becomes a node) and I would need to adapt.

Comment: It was just increasing the number of samples since some mixes do not match the desired one, adding an intermediate sample corrects that. On the other hand, I have the habit of making each answer as close as possible to what is desired.